# Infinite Loop in MIPS32

Tags: assembly, mips, infinite-loop

I have this program in MIPS that I have created, but while going through the code, line by line, I keep getting an infinite loop in QtSpim. As a result it displays the first message without anything displaying afterwards. The purpose of the function within the source code (MaxMin) is to return the maximum value and the minimum value in $v1 and $v0 respectively, given an array integers of length "N". Any advice on inproving the code would be of great help, thanks!

```
#Function MaxMin(&X, N, Min, Max)
# "X" is the address of the array passed to the function in $a0
# "N" is the length of the array passed to the function in $a1
# The function returns two values:
# 1: The minimum value of the array, returned in $v0.
# 2: The maximum value of the array, returned in $v1.
#######################################################
#In Pseudocode:
# 
#
#   $v0 = 0;
#   $v1 = 0;
#   
#   while(a1 > 0)
#   {
#       $a1 = $a1 - 1; #Decrement counter
#       $t0 = Mem(a0); #Obtain value from memory
#       $a0 = $a0 + 4; #Point to next address
#       if (value < $t0)
#       {
#           $v0 = value;
#       }
#       else if(value > $t0)
#       {
#           $v1 = value;
#       }
#           
#       
#   }
#   
#   return
#}
##########################################################

        .data
array:  .word       10, -5, 22, 57, 59, 63, 117, -100
msg1:   .asciiz "\n The lowest value in the array is: "
msg2:   .asciiz "\n The highest value in the array is: "

        .globl main
        .text
main:
        li $v0, 4     #System call code for print string
        la $a0, msg1  #load address into msg1. into $a0
        syscall 

        la $a0, array #Initialize address parameter
        li $a1, 8     #Initialize length parameter
        jal MaxMin    #Calls function MaxMin 

        #------------MaxMin Function---------------#
MaxMin: 

        li $v0, 0  #Parameter for maxumum value
        li $v1, 0  #Parameter for minimum value
        li $t1, 0  #Holds old value of $t0 
        li $t2, 0  #Holds old value of $t0 
repeatd:
        beqz $a1, Return  #If $a1 <= 0 Exit Program
        addi $a1, $a1, -1 #Decrement counter 
        lw   $t0, 0($a0)  #Obtain value from the array
        addi $a0, $a0, 4 #Increment value of array pointer for next element
        bgt  $t0, $t1, maximum #if $t0 > $t1 goto maximum
        blt  $t0, $t2, minimum #if $t0 < $t2 goto minimum

maximum: 

        move $t1, $t0  #Move value of $t0 to $t1 
        move $v1, $t0  #Move value of $t1 to $v1 
        b repeatd      #Branch back to Loop 

        minimum:

        move $t2, $t0  #Move value of $t0 to $t2
        move $v0, $t2  #Move value of $t1 to $v0 
        b repeatd         #Branch back to Loop

Return: 
        jr $ra       #Return values 

        #-------------MaxMin Function---------------#

        move $a0, $v0 #Min value returned from $v0 moved to $a0
        li   $v0, 1   #Calls system code to print integer
        syscall

        li  $v0, 4    #Calls code to print string 
        la  $a0, msg2 #load address of msg2 to $a0
        syscall

        li  $v0, 1    #System call code for printing integer
        move $a0, $v1 #Maximum value returned from $v1 moved to $a0
        syscall 

        li  $v0, 10   #Terminate program and return control to system 
        syscall
```

Comment: SPIM has a debugger built in.  Which exact loop is infinite?  (i.e. which instructions?)  Is it from `MaxMin:` to `jr $ra`?  

Is so, that's because `jal MaxMin` sets the return address to the start of the function.  (i.e. you fall through into the function that you just called.  Put instructions to exit your program after the `jal MaxMin` instruction).  Or *don't* put MaxMin in the middle of your main function.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I have traced through it with SPIM and it keeps repeating from the beginning of `MaxMin:` to `jr $ra`. I will try your suggestion, it seemed unusual as I thought it may have been one of the registers losing their value because of the `jal`. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If you have details from using a debugger, put them in the question next time so other people don't have to waste time running your code in their head.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I am relatively new to stack overflow, but I will do that next time around.